# WPFToolkit Accordion ArgumentOutOfRangeException when removing item from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, accordion, observablecollection, wpftoolkit, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm having trouble with the accordion control from WPFToolkit. The control is bound to an ObservableCollection. When i try to remove items from the collection which were added after initialization of the collection, i get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. This occures only if the item is not selected.
Here is my code:

```
private void AddNewReservation()
    {
        var res = new Reservation();
        var rvm = new ReservationViewModel(res);
        Reservations.Add(rvm);
        rvm.DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(
            param => Reservations.Remove(rvm));
        rvm.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => SaveReservation(res, rvm);
    }
```

My goal here is to add a ReservationViewModel containing an empty reservation model to the ObesrvableCollection. As long as the Model/ViewModel has no valid content it shouldn't be added to the Repositrory. 
So what am i doing wrong here or is this a known bug in wpftoolkit?
Heres my StackTrace:

```
bei System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
bei System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index)
bei System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.InternalItemAt(Int32 index)
bei System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.GetItemAt(Int32 index)
bei System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.GetItemAt(Int32 index)
bei System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
bei System.Windows.Controls.Accordion.UnselectItem(Int32 index, Object item)
bei System.Windows.Controls.Accordion.ChangeSelectedIndex(Int32 oldIndex, Int32 newIndex)
bei System.Windows.Controls.Accordion.OnSelectedIndexPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
bei System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
bei System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
bei System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
bei System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
bei System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
bei System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
bei System.Windows.Controls.Accordion.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)
bei System.Windows.Controls.Accordion.OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
bei System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemCollectionChanged2(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
bei System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
bei System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
bei System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.OnViewCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
bei System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList`1.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, Type managerType)
bei System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args)
bei System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionChangedEventManager.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
bei System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
bei System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChangedWithAdjustedIndex(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args, Int32 adjustedOldIndex, Int32 adjustedNewIndex)
bei System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
bei System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
bei System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
bei System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.RemoveItem(Int32 index)
bei System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Remove(T item)
bei NORDWIND_RS.ViewModel.BookingViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass17.<AddNewReservation>b__15(Object param)
```

I'll be thankfull for any advice,

Comment: Getting the same problem with the according control. I'm beginning to believe that it has an issue. In my case, I can delete any item up to the last item, but if I try to delete the last item from the bound collection, the accordianlist throws.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack solving the problem for now and small collections, but this shouldn't be the way. So if somone finds something better, please tell me.

```
private void AddNewReservation()
    {
        var res = new Reservation();
        var rvm = new ReservationViewModel(res);
        Reservations.Add(rvm);
        rvm.DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(
            param =>
            {
                Reservations = new ObservableCollection<ReservationViewModel>(Reservations.Where(r => r != rvm));
            });
        rvm.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => SaveReservation(res, rvm);
    }
```